# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0; why a[0][0] has ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException problem?

Tags: java, arrays

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Main{
    private static char[][] a = new char[5][5];
    public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException{
        int res = 0;
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int n = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
        while (n -- != 0){
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i ++){
                // for (int j = 0; j <5; j ++){
                    a[i] = in.readLine().toCharArray();
                // } 
            }
            
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i ++){
                for (int j = 0; j < 4 ; j ++){
                    if (a[i][j] != '1'){
                        a[i][j] = '1';
                        if(a[i][j + 1] == '1') {
                            a[i+1][j + 1]='0';
                        }else {
                            a[i+1][j + 1]='1';
                        }
                        res ++;
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println(res);
        }
        
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me?QAQ
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
at Main.main(Main.java:18)

Answer (score 0):

`Index 0 out of bounds for length 0` means Java was told to get the element with the index 0 (so the 0+1=1st element) out of an array that had a length of 0, aka. was empty - which can't work.

Since the error occurred in line 18 which is `if (a[i][j] != '1'){` it means that either `a` has a length of 0 (which should not happen since you're parsing a text file) or `j` is the array with a length of 0. This may happen if you're parsing a line that is empty.

To tell you how to fix the issue i'd need to know what you were trying to do (which I don't). But know you hopefully know what caused the error and are able to fix it yourself.

Happy coding!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).